# How to call ALSA allocation #define from JNA?

Tags: java, c, jna, alsa

I am trying to use JNA to call [ALSA](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/index.html) library functions from Java. I have been successful calling the basic open/close APIs snd_pcm_open() and snd_pcm_close() so I know I have the library loading OK and the basics right.

The first thing my application needs to do with ALSA is call snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca() to allocate a hardware parameter structure. But this is defined in the [C header file](http://alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/pcm_8h-source.html) as a macro, not a symbol:

```
#define snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(ptr) __snd_alloca(ptr, snd_pcm_hw_params)
```

For a C application it would be called like this:

```
snd_pcm_hw_params_t *params;
snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&params);
```

and "params" is then passed to many subsequent API calls.

I am not much of a C expert, I cannot figure out exactly what this is doing. I expected a memory allocation of a structure, but the next line in the header file defines snd_pcm_hw_params like:

```
int snd_pcm_hw_params(snd_pcm_t *pcm, snd_pcm_hw_params_t *params);
```

So does that mean the macro is returning a pointer to a function? How can I model this in JPA?

Comment: allocation of hardware parameters is typically done using `snd_pcm_hw_params_malloc`. the function you're talking about allocates memory on the stack instead of the heap. I'm not a java expert but I don't think stack allocation will work for java applications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function returns a pointer to a structure whose definition you do not know. (This is why you need all those accessor functions.)

`alloca()` allocates memory from the stack, which implies that it's freed as soon as the current function returns. This means that you cannot wrap this into a function to be called from Java.

Instead of `snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca()`, use `snd_pcm_hw_params_malloc()`, and don't forget to call `snd_pcm_hw_params_free()` at the correct time.

Comment: Yes, my lack of expertise in C plus blindly following an ALSA sample C program led me down the wrong API path. Wrote the JNA definitions for `snd_pcm_hw_params_malloc()` and it all works fine. Thanks also to @tay10r with the same answer.